# Random mysql errors but mysql shows different query then send

Tags: php, mysql, loops, random

I have a script that loops trough 2000 client records and copy them in an other database. Sometimes it runs perfectly and sometimes it returns a mysql error with a message that does not corresponds with the query send in PHP. Here is the error message (**P   A   K'2012-12-04 11:05:09'
            )
            O  DU LIC TE  EY UPDA**):

```
    [0] => Array
        (`enter code here`
        [Level] => Error
        [Code] => 1064
        [Message] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'P   A   K'2012-12-04 11:05:09'
        )
            O  DU LIC TE  EY UPDA' at line 45
        )
```

The query printed in PHP when the error occures:

```
    INSERT INTO
                `clients`
            (
                `klantId`,
                `naam`,
                `adres`,
                `postcode`,
                `plaats`,
                `telefoon`,
                `mobiel`,
                `fax`,
                `email`,
                `website`,
                `post_adres`,
                `post_postcode`,
                `post_plaats`,
                `kvknummer`,
                `btwnummer`,
                `rekeningnr`,
                `postbanknr`,
                `mailing`,
                `created`,
                `modified`
            )VALUES
            (
                1134,
                'Naam',
                'Adres 9L',
                '1234 SG',
                'Plaats',
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                'www.test.nl',
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                1,
                '2012-12-04 11:05:09',
                '2012-12-04 11:05:09'
            )
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                `naam`=VALUES(`naam`),
                `adres`=VALUES(`adres`),
                `postcode`=VALUES(`postcode`),
                `plaats`=VALUES(`plaats`),
                `telefoon`=VALUES(`telefoon`),
                `mobiel`=VALUES(`mobiel`),
                `fax`=VALUES(`fax`),
                `email`=VALUES(`email`),
                `website`=VALUES(`website`),
                `post_adres`=VALUES(`post_adres`),
                `post_postcode`=VALUES(`post_postcode`),
                `post_plaats`=VALUES(`post_plaats`),
                `kvknummer`=VALUES(`kvknummer`),
                `btwnummer`=VALUES(`btwnummer`),
                `rekeningnr`=VALUES(`rekeningnr`),
                `postbanknr`=VALUES(`postbanknr`),
                `mailing`=VALUES(`mailing`),
                `created`=VALUES(`created`),
                `modified`=VALUES(`modified`)
                ;
```

My script is running intern in the company and the database runs extern in a datacenter. Script runs 50% right 50% with error...

Thanks in advance!!

Added script with loop:

```
`
    $dbcon = getDbConnection();
    $aClients = getClients(); // return objects
    foreach ($aClients AS $oClient) {
    $sQuery = ' INSERT INTO
        `clients`
    (
        `klantId`,
        `naam`,
        `adres`,
        `postcode`,
        `plaats`,
        `telefoon`,
        `mobiel`,
        `fax`,
        `email`,
        `website`,
        `post_adres`,
        `post_postcode`,
        `post_plaats`,
        `kvknummer`,
        `btwnummer`,
        `rekeningnr`,
        `postbanknr`,
        `mailing`,
        `created`,
        `modified`
    )VALUES
    (
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->id) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->naam) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->adres) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->postcode) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->plaats) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->telefoonnummer) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->mobielnummer) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->faxnummer) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->emailadres) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->website) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->afwijkend_adres) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->afwijkend_postcode) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->afwijkend_plaats) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->kvknummer) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->btwnummer) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->bankrekening) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->postbank) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->mailing == 'ja' ? 1 : 0) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->created) . ',
        ' . $dbcon->real_escape_string($oClient->modified) . '
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `naam`=VALUES(`naam`),
        `adres`=VALUES(`adres`),
        `postcode`=VALUES(`postcode`),
        `plaats`=VALUES(`plaats`),
        `telefoon`=VALUES(`telefoon`),
        `mobiel`=VALUES(`mobiel`),
        `fax`=VALUES(`fax`),
        `email`=VALUES(`email`),
        `website`=VALUES(`website`),
        `post_adres`=VALUES(`post_adres`),
        `post_postcode`=VALUES(`post_postcode`),
        `post_plaats`=VALUES(`post_plaats`),
        `kvknummer`=VALUES(`kvknummer`),
        `btwnummer`=VALUES(`btwnummer`),
        `rekeningnr`=VALUES(`rekeningnr`),
        `postbanknr`=VALUES(`postbanknr`),
        `mailing`=VALUES(`mailing`),
        `created`=VALUES(`created`),
        `modified`=VALUES(`modified`)
    ;';
    $dbcon->query($sQuery);
}`
```

Last edit:
Tried the script on the same server as the database server and then it does not happen. It happens somewhere over the line...

The setting is: script runs on server A and database runs on server B. Not the same network so the internet is used for database connection. Somewhere data get lost...

Comment: Is your error message really missing random letters? Are you str_replacing a query at some point?

Comment: Probably there is some data containing apostrophe - that occurs mainly within names or street names. In that case the query is not properly ended.

Comment: This is the exact output. Nothing happens. Just inserting the clients in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't santize the input well. If in PHP you have to make all values valid with mysql_real_escape_string()

'P   A   K'2012-12-04 11:05:09' looks like you have a ' to many, wich causes the error. Escape this by \'

Querys work, or they don't. No 50-50 change with good coding; so if the query works, there's a problem with some input.

Comment: This is what it is, the query is printed out of the $sQuery variable. There is no single quote and all fields are escaped in PHP. Query looks good but somehow it's deformed in some way. And about the 50-50 change, I also did thought that...

Comment: Then the problem is maybe in the looping. Can you post the script doing the looping?

Comment: I added the script in the question post

Comment: Tried the script on the same server as the database server and then it does not happen. It happens somewhere over the line...

The setting is: script runs on server A and database runs on server B. Not the same network so the internet is used for database connection. Somewhere data get lost...